# Get value of key based on value of key of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of object

```
 [{chainTypeCode: "DIRECT", chainTypeId: "1"},
  {chainTypeCode: "MAGT", chainTypeId: "2"},
  {chainTypeCode: "MAGT_AGT", chainTypeId: "3"},
  {chainTypeCode: "MAGT_AGT_SAGT", chainTypeId: "4"}]
```

and I want to make a function `getChainTypeCode(chainTypeId)` in which if I pass a `chainTypeId`, it returns with a `chainTypeCode`

Comment: use `find` inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`

```
function getChainTypeCode(chainTypeId, chainTypeList) {
    return chainTypeList.find(chainType => chainType.chainTypeId == chainTypeId).chainTypeCode;
}

var obj = [{chainTypeCode: "DIRECT", chainTypeId: "1"},
  {chainTypeCode: "MAGT", chainTypeId: "2"},
  {chainTypeCode: "MAGT_AGT", chainTypeId: "3"},
  {chainTypeCode: "MAGT_AGT_SAGT", chainTypeId: "4"}];

var result = getChainTypeCode(1, obj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This it returning with the whole object. I want only `chainTypeCode`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `find()`

```
getCode = (arr, id)=> arr.find(p=>p.chainTypeId == id).chainTypeCode
```